# How to repeat the same SQL query for different column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a same SQL query with different column values, i.e: I have a table like below:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+
| ENAME  | EID   | BASIC Salary  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| AAA    | 111   | 12345         |
| BBB    | 222   | 45678         |
| CCC    | 333   | 8965          |
| DDD    | 444   | 3654          |
| .............................. |
| ZZZ    | 555   | 12345         |
+--------+-------+---------------+
```

From the above table, I want to fetch the `EID` and `Salary` for group of employees. Please suggest me how to make a query for getting above data without executing multiple time.

Comment: can you please tell me what output you want?? u need to explain it little more

Comment: Can you write your expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT ENAME, EID, Salary FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE ENAME IN ('AAA','DDD','ZZZ');
```

or

```
SELECT ENAME, EID, Salary FROM <TABLENAME1> WHERE ENAME IN (SELECT ENAME FROM <TABLENAME2> WHERE <CRITERIA>);
```

Comment: ,above is the basic syntax for getting the data for tables containing 10 entries.like wise if my table having a 1000 entries and i want to get the data for some 200 employees at a time. so is it possible to write a query for getting the 200 employees data at a time.

Comment: If your 200 employees are saved in another table, you can write a subquery like SELECT ENAME, EID, Salary FROM <TABLENAME1> WHERE ENAME IN (SELECT ENAME FROM <TABLENAME2>) or if it matches some criteria you can write WHERE clause with that criteria. Let me know your requirement.

Comment: yes useful info..is it possible to  give a input from excel or notepad file.

Comment: Simple thing you can do if you have huge number of records is 1. Create Temporary table 2. Load all the employee names in that table from your excel or csv file (using LOAD DATA INFILE) 3. Execute above query to get required result. t. Clean up temporary table

Comment: thanks you very much for your suggestion. i will try and let you know the result.

Comment: @sivakumar Its cool.. As it is your first question, remind you to accept the answer. If the answer satisfied your requirements, you can accept by clicking on tick symbol on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntex is :

```
select columnname1, sum(columnname2) from tablename where condition.. group by columnname1
```

Here, you will be write a query look like :

```
 select EID, sum(salary) from table where EID in(101,102,103,104,...)
 group by EID
```

Here, If you want a 200 or 300 row of data then use skip and limit in sql. You will be write a query look like :

```
select EID, sum(salary) from table 
     group by EID limit 10 offset 0
```

where limit is a no of record and offset is a skip a record

Comment: ,above is the basic syntax for getting the data for tables containing 10 entries.like wise if my table having a 1000 entries and i want to get the data for some 200 employees at a time. so is it possible to write a query for getting the 200 employees data at a time

Comment: it's possible by where clause or limit and skip methods, i will be update a answer...

Comment: Yes it will work only if i select 200 records continuously. if i want to select the random records,is it works..?

Comment: yes, it will be work if you pass a offset like .. Limit 200 offset 0, second time  Limit 200 offset 200, third time  Limit 200 offset 400,...so on..